# access docker container in different subnet (bridge)

Tags: docker, networking

I would like to reach container which is in another subnet (different bridge). The src and dst bridge is connected via a veth-pair.

This is needed for a test setup in which I would like to manipulate the connection propperties (rate, latancy, etc.) between those bridges. My VMs in these bridges are able to ping each other but not the containers (either the VMs nor the other containers if they are connected to the other bridge.

First I startet up the container without any network configuration and tried to connect their veth counterparts on the host to those bridges which i also created manualy.

Actually I created those bridges indirect with

```
docker network create --subnet 192.168.1.0/26 \
  -o "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc"="true" \
  -o "com.docker.network.driver.mtu"="1500" \
  -o "com.docker.network.bridge.name"="br-side-a" \
  br-side-a
docker network create --subnet 192.168.1.64/29 \
  -o "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc"="true" \
  -o "com.docker.network.driver.mtu"="1500" \
  -o "com.docker.network.bridge.name"="br-side-b" \
  br-side-b
```

and connected them with

```
ip link add dev vsidea type veth peer name vsideb
brctl addif br-side-a vsidea
brctl addif br-side-b vsideb
ip addr add 192.168.1.10/26 dev vsidea
ip addr add 192.168.1.66/29 dev vsideb
ip link set vsidea up
ip link set vsideb up
```

VMs that I connected to those bridges (with IPs of the connected subnets) are able to ping each other.

My containers are startet like this:

```
docker run -ti --network br-side-a --ip 192.168.1.20 -p 10001:10000 --name csidea --privileged debian bash
docker run -ti --network br-side-a --ip 192.168.1.67 -p 10001:10000 --name csideb --privileged debian bash
```

I can ping all (gateway-ips, vsidea/b, ...) on both container of each subnet but not the IPs which I assigned to those containers. Nor could the VMs reach the container IPs.

I think docker does some routing/filtering which I must turn off but I have no idea how.

Comment: Bridges bridge frames on the same network. Routers route packets between different networks. A host sending a packet to a different network will create the frame for its configured gateway (the router, which is a host on a network that knows how to send traffic to the other network).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I found a solution to my problem. Like mentioned docker does filtering, I now know.

Docker automatically creates iptables rules to restrict network access for created bridges. To show them just use `iptables [-L|-S]` there should be three specific rule chains 'DOCKER-USER', 'DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1' and 'Docker-ISOLATION-STAGE-2'.

The rules in those isolation stage chains does prevent networking between my networks. They are in the form:

```
-I DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i <my_network> ! -o <my_network> -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE2
-I DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -i <my_network> ! -o <my_network> DROP
```

I first set the last rules from DROP to ACCEPT just to justify my discoveries. And see the networking works between those nets.

So I searched how to prevent docker to create those rules, but you can only disable creation of any iptables entries by docker not just some of them. Also it is not recommended to change the isolations chains, but the DOCKER-USER chain is for exactly that purpose. It will be evaluated before any other docker rules, so you can specify to accept these packages instead of dropping them. Add following rule for every subnet you will let to communicate `iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i <my_bridge_network> ! -o <my_bridge_network> ACCEPT`.

PS: Sorry for my english. I hope it is understandable, but if there are unbearable mistakes feel free to give me a hint how I could do better.